# get informed about ajax error in p:ajaxStatus

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, status

I have some ajax-operations, and if I execute one method, the Ajax-status displays me "error". I have no idea, what did fail.
Do you have any ideas, how I can fetch the ajax-error-message in case there is one to solve the problem?

```
    <!-- AJAX-STATUS INFO --> 
    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:64px;height:64px;position:fixed;right:5px;bottom:5px" id="aj">  
        <f:facet name="start">
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/loading.gif" />  
        </f:facet>   

        <f:facet name="complete">  
            <h:outputText value="Complete" />  
        </f:facet>  


        <f:facet name="prestart">
        <h:outputText value="Starting..." /> </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="error"> <h:outputText value="Error" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="success"> <h:outputText value="Success" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="default"> <h:outputText value="Ready" />
        </f:facet> 

    </p:ajaxStatus>
```

I can't fix the problem due to the fact that I don't know what did crash. My method is called by

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.booleanfield}" id="myonoffswitch" styleClass="onoffswitch-checkbox">
  <f:ajax event="click" render=":main" execute="@form" listener="#{bean.reload}"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

public void reload(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){...}
```

and the `reload()` method is executed without any errors, it finished without problems.

Somewhere after that the problem must occur? If I switch the button on, the Ajax status works fine. If i switch the button off, it says "error".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any problems without the listener? What does the `reload` method do - could you post the code?

Comment: One more thing  - if you want to inspect the error closer using for example Firebug then add something like `<script>$( document ).ajaxError(function( event ) { console.log(event);});</script>` in your markup so the event gets logged to Firebug's console.

Comment: If you're only interested in this for debugging, look in your browser's javascript console. If you're looking for a solution to communicate errors back to the end user, you should be adding `<p:messages/>` to your view and queue meaningful `FacesMessages` in your bean logic